# Is there any IMAP/POP3 rely and archiving server application?

Tags: email, proxy, sendmail, smtp, imap

Classic email setup:

```
[REAL-MAIL-SERVER] 
   [IMAP/POP3 >]  ---------> [EMAIL-CLIENT]
    [Storage]
```

**Is there any server application** (open source) that would permit to **store emails** and act like a **rely/proxy** between the client and the mail server ?

```
[REAL-MAIL-SERVER]           [PROXY-RELY-SERVER]
  [IMAP/POP3 >]   --------->   [< IMAP/POP3 >]  ---------> [EMAIL-CLIENT]
    [Storage]                    [Storage]
```

**The purpose here** is to keep emails data in a private location out of the main server and access it with a mobile/desktop clients (the email data would be kept at the "PROXY-RELY-SERVER" location only, client would connect to it, SMTP function is not needed). I found **[piler](http://www.mailpiler.org)** but i don't know yet if it could work like that.

**Otherwise** is there any email client that can act like an IMAP server for other clients to fetch emails from it? **Or** a simple **IMAP server** that can fetch other mailbox?

Comment: Do you expect to keep two different storages (but synced), both accessible from different clients ?
Or everything is capted by the 'proxy-rely-server' (as you named it) serving all clients ?

Comment: Is the 'proxy-rely-server' the common client

Comment: @user4089 i updated the question, everything would be captured by the "proxy-rely-server" serving all the clients; that proxy server **is not** the final client app.

Comment: If that proxy server is not the final client box, I edited my answer suggesting ISPConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume everything is captured by the 'proxy-rely-server' (as you named it) serving all clients (the easy way) and it's the common client.

You probably need a couple of [MRA and MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_agent_(infrastructure)) installed on your 'proxy-rely-server'.
The [MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent) will act as POP/IMAP server (for local use + other clients).
The [MRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_retrieval_agent) (some kind of special MUA) will fetch emails from the 'real-mail-server' and store them on the MDA.

You have the choice between [a lot of systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_server_software) to achieve this. I just can suggest that, for now, I'm using Dovecot as MDA and Getmail as MRA.

The drawback is that all emails should be erased on the 'real-mail-server' as no syncing is -easily- possible. That means you'll have to take care of backups...

[edit following you comment]

As the 'proxy-rely-server' is NOT the common client, but some kind of server box (I guess), and as I'm a lazy guy, I can suggest you having a look at [ISPConfig](https://www.ispconfig.org/) witch will do everything you need and a lot more. It's stable (based on debian or many other distros), very well [documented](https://www.ispconfig.org/documentation/), easy to [install](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-10-buster-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-1/), easy to use, and very easy to maintain.